# Handle project where the goals is to choose a new solution

Tags: project-management, scrum, decision-making

After my scrum certification, I had a chance to be selected as the team lead of a small project in my company. The goals is to made a choice on the new SAP the company will use. We are a team of 6 persons with cross skills.

But I don't know how to handle that. The most example that I saw was how to do that for IT project. But in this case, we don't even have to write a line of code, even if IT skills are required. What is the possible deliverable for this project ? Any advices on how to handle the teams ?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is a misfit for this site on many levels. First of all, it's not about software engineering, more likely project management, so it should be posted on that site. But then this doesn't look much like a possible project to be handled with Scrum by a team of 6 persons. If you want to accept the challenge anyway, you need to refine this ill-defined deliverable together with the product owner before starting the first sprint. But I would just walk up to the person who gave you this task and ask them what they really want and why they think your team should do it with Scrum.

Comment: Understand, I just came on the website and I will read the guide in details. Your comment is very helpful for me. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If the goal of the project is to make a decision (or more likely, to hand over a well-researched recommendation), then that decision **is** the deliverable. No need to overthink this.

And how to you handle a fact-finding project? Pretty much the same way as managing a system-building project actually. Presumably there will be phases  of requirements engineering (ask stakeholders which features the new environment should have and how important they are - e.g., is price most important? Longevity? Support? Performance?), planning (i.e. research into which solutions exhibit which of these characteristics and to what degree), testing (either interviewing other users of the systems, or test-deploying something and using it yourself), evaluation and documentation.

So a fact-finding project may have slightly different emphasis on the individual steps; perhaps there is less testing than in a programming project, and more documentation, since the final report is the most important outcome. But the steps themselves are rather similar in intent, and can be handled by conventional project management methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you have some good reading designed to handle that in team. I mean project development method ? For example, should I ask all the teams to study the same solution to fill the comparaison matrix or should I ask each member to study one individual solution and defend it ? I believe people have already face this kind of project, where can I meet them ?

Comment: You will definitely meet some on the project management sub-forum: https://pm.stackexchange.com